# Java: Send and recive an Object over Socket

Tags: java, sockets, object

I am a student and learning Network Programming and have a some problem.

This is my client:

```
public class Test2Client_Tranfer_An_Obj {

Socket socket = null;
ObjectOutputStream out;
ObjectInputStream in;

public Test2Client_Tranfer_An_Obj() {
    try {
        socket = new Socket("localhost", 12345);

        out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        System.out.println("Ready");

        System.out.println("" + in.readUTF());
        System.out.println("" + in.readUTF());
        System.out.println("Recived");

        out.writeUTF("hihi");

        System.out.println("Sended");




    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Client");
    Test2Client_Tranfer_An_Obj test = new Test2Client_Tranfer_An_Obj();
}
```

}

This my Server:

```
public class Test2Server_Tranfer_An_Obj {

ServerSocket serverSocket;
ObjectOutputStream out;
ObjectInputStream in;

public Test2Server_Tranfer_An_Obj() {

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(12345);
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

        out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        System.out.println("Ready!");
        out.writeUTF("huhu");
        out.writeUTF("hoho");
        System.out.println("Sended");

        String s = in.readUTF();
        System.out.println("" + s);
        System.out.println("Recived");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Server");
    Test2Server_Tranfer_An_Obj demo = new Test2Server_Tranfer_An_Obj();

}
```

}

But, when i run my program, this result:

Server Console

> Server
>   Ready!
>   Sended

Client Console

> Client Ready

Anybody can tell me why and what i can do?
Thank for reading!
Hope recive you answer

Comment: read about serializing (Serializable interface), this is java way to Your target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object Stream is overkill in this case.  You are not actually using writeObject/readObject and using `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream` would do what you want.

In this particular case, an Object Stream is buffered, which means that small writes are buffered until you either `flush()` or `close()` the stream to improve performance.  As you don't do either, the `writeUTF` only writes to memory, not the Socket.

c.f. Data Streams are **not** buffered by default.

Comment: Thank for answering!

Answer (score 0):

In your server after write to the outputstream. you have to add `out.flush()` to write to socket